# JBoss (liferay) no context.xml so where to put JNDI resource

Tags: jboss, jndi, liferay

I've got the order to switch from Liferay on tomcat, to Liferay on JBoss.
One issue I'm having is that unlike in tomcat, I can't seem to find a context.xml in liferay-portal-6.0.5\jboss-5.1.0\server\default\conf

Will it work if I just copy the context.xml from my tomcat installation to my jboss installation? (I don't know if JBoss scans that folder).

Or is there an alternative location where I can put my resource?

```
<Resource name="jdbc/x" auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="y"
              username="z" password="A" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
              maxWait="-1"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a file named "*- ds.xml" in the deploy directory server with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/myds</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:sid</connection-url>
    <user-name></user-name>
    <password></password>
    <new-connection-sql>SELECT * FROM DUAL</new-connection-sql>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT * FROM DUAL</check-valid-connection-sql>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```